# Unable to import snapshot meta file in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Running `yb-admin import_snapshot` and getting the following error.  Looking for a pointer as before running the import snapshot I drop and load the schema/tables from the snapshot schema sql

```
Error running import_snapshot: Not found (yb/master/catalog_manager_ent.cc:1344): Unable to import snapshot meta file /tmp/yb2/8a347ab6-654e-4287-b3f0-13717a21bf6d/8a347ab6-654e-4287-b3f0-13717a21bf6d.snapshot: Not found new tablet with expected partition keys: - ?: INTERNAL_ERROR (master error 34)
```

Using YugabyteDB 2.7.1.1 and YSQL layer on ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

That version is relatively old.  There were some backup/restore fixes for YSQL in later versions, and they may handle this issue.

This looks like a mismatch of partitioning between current table and snapshot table. It sounds like commit 2f9d4dcaacff5b3fad5e2016c4d73b9101196d38:

> Return error like:

```
> Wrong number of tablets in created PGSQL_TABLE_TYPE table hints in namespace id 000030af000030008000000000000000: 2 (expected 6)
```

> instead of unclear:

```
> Not found new tablet with expected partition keys:  - UU
>
```

2.8 and 2.11 should have the fix.